# C++ deleting children basing on parent's pointer

Tags: c++, object, pointers, parent, children

Let's say that I have class A:

```cpp
class A {
    A();
};
```

and class B being a child of A:

```cpp
class B : public A {
    B() : A();
    ~B();
};
```

and a vector of A pointers:

```cpp
std::vector<A*> a_pointers;
```

Now, I initialize everything with:

```cpp
B* b_obj = new B();

a_pointers.push_back(b_obj);
```

How do I delete b_obj object? Should it be something like this?

```cpp
delete a_pointers[0];
```

Would it work? If not, how should it be done?

Comment: As long as destructor is declared virtual in base, delete on parent pointer will call the destructor of derived class

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll want to give A a virtual destructor (see [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/virtual-destructor/) for why):

```
class A {
    A();
public:
    virtual ~A() = default; 
};
```

At which point calling `delete a_pointers[0]` will fully destruct `b_obj`.

Answer (score 0):

If you specifically refer to the local variable `B* b_obj` then you don't need to delete it. The local variable resides in the stack and will be cleaned when you return from the function it was declared in.

If you are referring to the object that was created and assigned to `B* b_obj` (i.e. the object that was created by new() and then it's reference was copied into the vector), then you would need to delete it explicitly by calling `delete()` sometime later on (you would probably need to iterate through the vector and delete all of its items).

Another important thing to notice is that you would also need to declare your destructor as virtual as Nathan Pierson said.